# Elasticsearch daily/monthly aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to build daily/monthly aggregation query.

1. Is the only solution to create ranges -> from... to... for each day/month? I can generate ranges but it seems that it can be other way to achieve that.
2. How can I format from... to... epoch milis to yyyy-mm-dd for each result?

   ```
   {
    "aggs": {
      "aggs_sum_amount": {
        "filters": {
          "filters": {
            "Amount1": {
              ...
            },
            "Amount2": {
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "range": {
            "date_range": {
              "field": "dateField",
              "ranges": [
                {
                  "from": "1613347200000",
                  "to": "1613433600000"
                },
                {
                  "from": "1613433600000",
                  "to": "1613520000000"
                }
                ...
              ]
            },
            "aggs": {
              "sum_amount": {
                "sum": {
                  "field": "amount"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   ```

   }

Example response

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "aggs_sum_amountPLN": {
      "buckets": {
        "Amount1": {
          "doc_count": 26,
          "range": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "1613347200000-1613433600000",
                "from": 1.6133472E12,
                "from_as_string": "1613347200000",
                "to": 1.6134336E12,
                "to_as_string": "1613433600000",
                "doc_count": 0,
                "sum_amount": {
                  "value": 0.0
                }
              },
              {
                ...
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "Amount2": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [date_histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) aggregation
It lets you specify a range and an interval for which you want to get the different buckets for.

This example on the linked page is quite self explanatory.

I've updated it to match your use-case:

```
POST /sales/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "sales_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "calendar_interval": "1M",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd" 
      }
    }
    "aggs": {
      "sum_amount": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "amount"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response should be something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "sales_over_time": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2015-01-01",
          "key": 1420070400000,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "sum_amount": {
            "value": 15.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2015-02-01",
          "key": 1422748800000,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum_amount": {
            "value": 10.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2015-03-01",
          "key": 1425168000000,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum_amount": {
            "value": 25.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```